# Where are panel launchers stored in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: gnome, launcher, gnome-panel, metacity

In earlier versions of Ubuntu, user-created launchers for the top panel were stored in the directory `~/.gnome2/panel2.d/default/launchers`.  This is no longer the case in the current versions.  The Official Ubuntu Documentation at present lacks even the most basic information on this topic (the [HowToAddaLauncher](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToAddaLauncher) page "needs updating to include the latest versions of Ubuntu").

In Ubuntu 14.04 running Gnome Metacity Flashback, where are the files for the user-created panel lauchers located?  Can these simply be backed up and copied into the appropriate directory of a new installation of the OS to provide a customized top panel upon reboot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom application launchers are stored in `~/.config/gnome-panel/launchers`. You can backup these launchers, but they won't be automatically added to panel if you copy launchers in that directory. You can drag&drop these launchers to panel.

Otherwise panel settings are stored in gsettings/dconf under /org/gnome/gnome-panel. I don't know if there is easy way to backup/restore only gnome-panel settings.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  Is there a command-line way to add the launchers in ~/.config/gnome-panel/launchers to the panel?  To drag and drop you have to open up the Files application, enable "show hidden files," hunt through numerous directories, etc.  I am unable to corroborate your second paragraph.  There is no directory /org; indeed the command "sudo find . -type d -name gnome-panel" yields only the ~/.config subdirectories in users' homes and subdirectories of /usr/share and /usr/lib.

Comment: (The aforementioned "sudo find ..." run from the root directory, of course.  But I guess your second paragraph means that upon running dconf-editor, under org-->gnome-->gnome-panel-->layout-->objects, one can find a reference of sorts to each panel launcher.)  Anyhow, I'm inclined to accept your response as a solution.  To do what I sought to do in my original question, run a cron job to back up the `launchers` subdirectory, and after copying it to a new installation run `nautilus ~/.config/gnome-panel/launchers`, select launchers (en masse if desired), and drag to panel.